# Company-Employee database design

Tags: sql-server, database-design, primary-key

I am trying to build a SQL 2005 database that has a Company data table and an Employee data table.  Each company should have an Employee 1, Employee 2, and so on.  I realize that each Employee record would have a PK of both their EmployeeID and their CompanyID, but I haven't for the life of me determined the best way of doing this?

Any ideas?

**Let me me clarify this a bit**

Each company can have its own employee #1, #2, etc.  Say I have a stored procedure that returns a specific employee by passing in the company id and the requested employee id.

```
exec dbo.GetEmployee @CompanyID = 1, @EmployeeID = 45
```

Keeping in mind that Company 1 can have an Employee 1 and Company 2 can have a different Employee 1, how can I do this?  How can I have an incremental primary key for employees unique for each company?

Comment: Can you explain the rationale behind why you can't just have one series of employee numbers across all companies? It would simplify things immensely and the added complexity seems unnecessary.

Comment: I was trying to be as general business-wise as possible before, but here is exactly what i am trying to do:  I have an auction system, where multiple auctions can be in this application.  Each auction has a set of bidders, each given a bidder #.  These #'a are how the bidders bid on items.

Comment: Comment Part 2: I want each new auction to start with bidder #1 and upwards.  If it doesn't, then it could be that a new auction has bidders starting with 1,000,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't.

You create a primary key on the employee table, over the company ID and the employee ID. That takes care of the unique constraint.

However you cannot have the employee ID increment automatically, instead in the insert you need to wrap it in a transaction and do something like

```
insert @companyID, max(employeeID)+1 from employees where companyID=@companyID into employee
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid I was going to have to do something with MAX().  Thanks blowdart.

Comment: A better answer is that you SHOULDN'T. It is a bad design that is going to bite you eventually.

Comment: I agree with JohnFx.  Please do not do this in a production application, you are are setting the stage for future problems.

Comment: And if you do, please post the name of your company so I can make sure not to inherit this system by accident one day. =)

Comment: Well yea, it's not wonderfully optimal, but it meets the specs. The problem is the specs ask for something SQL can't do without some jumping through hoops.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is a data modeling question:

If Employees can only work for one Company, then you could have the CompanyID just be a foreign key reference in the Employee table, and EmployeeID be something unique to any given person (like SSID for example).

If Employees can work for more than one Company, then you have a many-to-many relationship, which would require a third table -- named something like CompanyEmployee, consisting of CompanyID and EmployeeID.

That help?

OR, is your question simply:

"How do I do a compound primary key in SQL Server"?

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use an incremental key for each employee that is unique within a given company.  I can't use SSID.

Comment: If "SSID" means Social Security ID, I'd advise you to avoid it.  Better to go with a surrogate, generated key.  Lots of laws prohibiting the use of Social Security # for that sort of thing.

Comment: If you just use a single incrementing column for employee ID it will still be unique within a given company, it will also be unique across companies (a good thing).

Answer (score 2):

Based on you comment to Jamo, you need two employee IDs. One that is unique by employer and one that is unique throughout the database. Then you have these tables:

```
Employees
E_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL
E_NAME
E_SSID
etc.

Companies
C_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL
C_NAME
etc.

Employment
CE_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL
C_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (Companies.C_ID)
E_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (Employees.E_ID)
LOCAL_E_ID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL
```

C_ID is a unique identifier for a company.
E_ID is a unique identifier for an employee in the database.
CE_ID is a unique identifier for the employment table to make it easier to do updates.
LOCAL_E_ID is unique by company. You will need to create some kind of trigger to create this number.

Comment: Thanks joe.  you got the best solution so far.  The assignment of LOCAL_E_ID is the main problem I have right now...

Comment: You probably need an on insert trigger for that column which does a select max(local_e_id)+1 from employment where c_id = :new_c_id or something like that. My mssql trigger syntax is rusty.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you probably are barking up the wrong tree.

If the employeeID is assigned as an autoincrementing (and thus arbitrary) number, there is no reason to restart the employeeID for each company. If you think I am mistaken, please provide an example and I'll adjust my answer.

This design is just going to create an unnecessarily complex design. For example your stored procedure really ought to take a single EmployeeID and that employee record would then be used to determine the company.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's a foreign key in there somewhere.  It's a 1:many relationship between Employee and Company, assuming that an Employee could only work for one Company at a time.  Both Employee and Company would have a PK, and Employee would have an FK that references the Company PK.

I'd urge you to use surrogate keys for both Company and Employee.  Keeping business logic out of keys is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a table called Company with a Primary Key column CompanyID and then I'd have a table called Employee with a Primary Key column of EmployeeID and a Foreign Key column of CompanyID. Of course you would have EmployeeName and CompanyName and any other appropriate columns on each table.